# Работа с jRadioButton в java

Tags: java, swing

Добавляю на форму радиокнопки таким образом:

```
for (int i=1;i<vote.size();i++){
        javax.swing.JRadioButton radio = new javax.swing.JRadioButton(vote.get(i).toString());
        jPanel4.add(radio, i-1);
        buttonGroup1.add(radio);
        jPanel4.validate();
    }
```

Как после этого узнать индекс выбранной?

*vote* - лист подписей к кнопкам. И по количество подписей является количеством кнопок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

объявите i final'ом, и в слушателе используйте, модификация вашего примера:

```
for (int i=1;i<vote.size();i++){
        final fI = i;
        javax.swing.JRadioButton radio = new javax.swing.JRadioButton(vote.get(i).toString());
        radio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                       //fI -  доступна для использования
                }
            });

        jPanel4.add(radio, i-1);
        buttonGroup1.add(radio);
        jPanel4.validate();
    }
```

Comment: Ругнется на i++;

Comment: Да, точно. поправил

Answer (score 2):

Используйте листенеры, например, [как показано](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/ItemListenerforJRadioButton.htm).